# making json array in a method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on an angular application. In my component I have a method as follows:

```
createPath(node, currentPath = []){
  if(node.parent !==null) {
     return createPath(node.parent, [node.data.name, ...currentPath])
  } else {
    return [node.data.name, ...currentPath];
   } 
}
```

Here I am recursively calling the method till node.parent becomes null. If it becomes null it will just give me node.data.name. In my each node, I have id also, which I can access using node.data.id. I want to store it in array in following format:

```
[{
 id:1, //can access using node.data.id
 name:"myName"  //can access using node.data.name. which I am getting in above method.
}
]
```

This is just example at runtime I can have n number of item, so I want to write a dynamic code which work
in all condition.

I want to modify my above code and make this data in this method only.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
createPath(node, currentPath = []){
  if(node.parent !== null) {
     return createPath(node.parent, [{id: node.data.id, name: node.data.name}, ...currentPath])
  } else {
    return [{id: node.data.id, name: node.data.name}, ...currentPath];
   } 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add this type of code above return method so that existing code is not disturbed?

Answer (score 0):

Is your array being returned as an array from another destination? Because currently this would work for one item, you should use `forEach()` and `push` them into the array, So you will have a new array entry, otherwise the first item will be taken into the list and that will be it.

Answer (score -1):

1. Intialiase an array to store your json objects as follows:
   array:any=[ ]
2. Wherever you want to create the array (for example above the return statement of else block) add the following lines:

   ```
   this.array.push(
    {
      id: node.data.id,
      name: node.data.name
    }
   )
   ```